# RX pin of ttyS0 is always high

Tags: uart

I am trying to configure a Pi 4 and eventually a CM3 for modbus communication. so far I have been able to see the TX send from the D+ and D- of the max485cpa+ but I have been unable to receive data via RX (via rs485 or rs232).

Today I set a meter on the RX pin and found that the pin was high, and I know that the Pi wont receive if RX is high.

Is this a defect of the board or is there a way to set RX low to receive data?

Comment: It's high because it's set as an input with a pull-up - as long as gpioinfo shows it as being an input, it will work as an input

Comment: It is set as an input but will not receive data. I’ve tested this in a number of different ways but the results are the same. My understanding is that with uart enabled the rx pin floats and when tested should read zero volts. Is this incorrect?

Comment: if it's set as an input it CAN receive data - perhaps you're sending device isn't sending data, perhaps your connections are incorrect, perhaps you haven't configured the pi correctly - no idea, but the fact that RX is high is NOT the problem

Answer (score 1):

For clarification and resolution.

The answer provided by Bravo is incorrect. The RX pin is always low when calling the port on Raspberry Pi as this is required to receive. This is well documented in the Datasheets and manuals for all of Raspberry's devices.

The issue, in this case, was with the client device that we tried to interface with. The engineer on their side did not use industry standards in the pin configuration, he also refuse to share his pin configuration claiming that they followed the standard. As a result the hardware on both sides was damaged.